# Deploy debian package for multiple distros into Jfrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

What is the right procedure to deploy a debian package built for different distros into the same Jfrog debian artifactory repo?

Just uploading to the same path, but with different `deb.distribution` properties does not work, they all get uploaded to the same place and clobber the previous upload.

Including the distribution name into the package name is ugly, but would of course work. Is there a better way?

Comment: It would appear as if the location on artifactory doesn't matter as far as satisfying `apt` requests. Testing to see if that's true. If it is, then simply uploading it onto an artifactory path specific for the distro would be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply post the different debian to different locations within the Jfrog artifactory repository. The trick is that the repository layout has nothing to do with the aptitude API, which retrieves debians regardless of their location according to the requested metadata (deb.distribution, deb.version etc).

Comment: Note that Jfrog Artifactory 5.x seems to have some trouble with this, but 6.1.4 works fine.